# jQuery method to a search box with a dropdown menu in it

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, user-interface

It's easier to show you what I am trying to do with jQuery. I'm looking to make a menu within an input field like Oodle has at the top of their site in their search bar: http://www.oodle.com/vehicle/ . Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started on the dropdown menu. The rest is probably styling.

[bgiframe explained](http://jetlogs.org/2008/05/09/jquery-fix-ie-select-box-z-index-bug/)

[actual bgiframe plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe)

Answer (score 0):

the menu is not within the input field,

1. Remove all borders via css from the input field
2. float the drop down trigger to the right
3. wrap both elements in another div to give the illusion of an input field

http://jsbin.com/eyatu

the example above should help in the right direction...

Answer (score -2):

They use an  tag, and lots of javaScript.

I think the best way to know how they're doing it is using FireBug to inspect the page.